# How to change all values of a column into unique integers?

Tags: python, pandas, loops

I'm working on a chess dataset, where I got a column for move_1, move_2, move_3 and so on...
each of these columns has the 'play code' made by the player. Each row is for a specific game and there are about 1000 rows.

```
  result move_1 move_2 move_3 ...
      1     e4     d4    Nc3  ...    
      1     d4    Nf3     c4  ...
      1     e4     d3    Nd2  ...
      1     d4     c4     d5  ...
      0     d4     c4    Nc3  ...

keeps going down...
```

what is the best way for me to change each unique value in each row/column to an assigned integer so I can do some analysis on it? 
I've done the following:

```
chess_df['move_2'].replace(to_replace=['Nf3', 'c4', 'd3','d4', 'Nc3'],
           value= [3, 2, 4, 1, 7],
           inplace=True)
```

where each 'play code' has it's assigned integer. So, 'd4' = 1, 'c4 = 2 and so on,  **on ALL rows**.

Problem is, this is NOT a great way of doing it since I need to find each and every unique code and replace it for a unique integer by columns... This will take ages, and it will be really confusing.

What I want is, move_1 column got 1000 rows and 45 unique 'play codes'. So each play code in it would become a number ranging from 1-45.

move_2 column has 1000 rows with 89 unique values where 25 of them are also in move_1 column. So I need to assign the 25 numbers already assigned in move_1 column + 64 **new** numbers. And so on...

So my question is:

How can I through **Python** code, create something that would automate the process of changing the 'play code' into a unique integer on **all rows and columns?**

Comment: hey @Ehsan, I had no idea! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple alternative is to stack everything into one Series, rank it, then unstack back. This way the rank is applied to the entire DataFrame. Here "d4" becomes 6 regardless of where it occurs.

```
df.filter(like='move_').stack().rank(method='dense').atype(int).unstack()
#   move_1  move_2  move_3
#0       8       6       1
#1       6       3       4
#2       8       5       2
#3       6       4       7
#4       6       4       1
```

---

Alternatively you could use the `return_inverse` argument of `np.unique` and re-create the DataFrame.

```
arr = df.filter(like='move')
pd.DataFrame(np.unique(arr, return_inverse=True)[1].reshape(arr.shape),
             index=arr.index,
             columns=arr.columns)

#   move_1  move_2  move_3
#0       7       5       0
#1       5       2       3
#2       7       4       1
#3       5       3       6
#4       5       3       0
```

Comment: I'm getting the following error:

```'Index' object has no attribute 'remove_unused_levels''```

Comment: Fixed the problem by adding underline after move and fixing 'astype' Thank you!!!!
df.filter(like='move_').stack().rank(method='dense').astype(int).unstack()

Answer (score 2):

Does this help?

```py
unique_vals = chess_df['move_2'].unique()
chess_df['move_2'].replace(to_replace=unique_vals,
           value= list(range(len(unique_vals))),
           inplace=True)
```

Comment: Oh man, that seems really simple! By doing this, will the unique values from one column be pushed to the next one too?
Edit: just tried and the values are assigned by the column. Is label encoding able to keep the assigned integer in each column the same?

Comment: I believe this is better than label encoding because it would require extra lines (label encoding takes an array, not a matrix). Also, you beat me, I thought the same thing! +1 :)

Comment: @DanWilkin I just had a second look at the question. Now, the thing is chess games can have a plethora of moves.  But the number of notations possible is finite. I think you should think of a way to convert the notation into a number. For eg: Nd4 = 3*100+4*10+4 = 244. Bc3 = 2*100+3*10+3. I assigned 2 to Bishop and 3 to Knight. Also, I substituted some placevalues for each position. Not  very sure if ALollz's solution would be able to fit in the memory successfully and so am suggesting this technique. If you like this technique, I can update my accordingly to give you an idea.

Comment: hey @paradoxlover damn, that's actually a really, really awesome idea! 
I've chosen chess games as a personal project to help a good friend of mine to analyze chess matches. I'm still learning (well, I'll always be learning), so I would actually deeply appreciate an idea of your suggestion! :) 
Thank you for your time!

Comment: Okay then, I will update my answer when I am free, mp by today evening. You can have a look at it!!!

Answer (score 0):

This would be my approach:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Move_1':['a1','b2','c3','c4'],
                   'Mode_2':['a1','f5','h6','b2']})

replacers = {k:list(set([x[0] for x in df.values.reshape(-1,1)])).index(k) for k in list(set([x[0] for x in df.values.reshape(-1,1)]))}
df_new = df.replace(replacers)
```

Output:

```
   Move_1  Mode_2
0       0       0
1       5       3
2       1       4
3       2       5
```

Essentially we are creating a dictionary with the chess positions as key and a unique number as value. This will be then used in `df.replace()` to perform the replacement across all the values in the df.

Answer (score 0):

This answer accounts all moves in `move_1`, then `move_2` and so on (I assume this is the way you described in question) and finds unique moves in ALL moves in the order mentioned and assigns them integer values:

```
moves = chess_df.loc[:,chess_df.columns!='result'].stack().sort_index(level=1).unique()
chess_df.replace(to_replace=moves,value=list(range(len(moves))),inplace=True)
```

In other words, it assigns integers to `move_1` first, then `move_2` (accounting for repetitions) and so on.

input/output for the example in question:

```
   result move_1 move_2 move_3
0       1     e4     d4    Nc3
1       1     d4    Nf3     c4
2       1     e4     d3    Nd2
3       1     d4     c4     d5
4       0     d4     c4    Nc3

   result  move_1  move_2  move_3
0       1       0       1       5
1       1       1       2       4
2       1       0       3       6
3       1       1       4       7
4       0       1       4       5
```